# upgrading TensorFlow on MacOS: Could not import setuptools which is required to install from a source distribution

Tags: python, tensorflow, upgrade, macos-sierra

I'm trying to upgrade my version of Tensorflow 
(currently installed 1.0.1 together with Python 2.7)
doing `sudo -H pip install --upgrade tensorflow`

I have this error log

> Collecting tensorflow   Downloading
>   tensorflow-1.1.0-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_11_x86_64.whl (30.9MB)
>       100% |████████████████████████████████| 30.9MB 50kB/s  Collecting protobuf>=3.2.0 (from tensorflow)   Downloading protobuf-3.3.0.tar.gz
>   (271kB)
>       100% |████████████████████████████████| 276kB 992kB/s
>   Could not import setuptools which is required to install from a source
>   distribution. Traceback (most recent call last): 
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py",
>   line 387, in setup_py
>       import setuptools  # noqa   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/**init**.py",
>   line 11, in 
>       from setuptools.extern.six.moves import filterfalse, map   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/extern/**init**.py",
>   line 1, in 
>       from pkg_resources.extern import VendorImporter ImportError: No module named extern

i don't understand because if I do

```
pip install setuptools
```

> Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages

thanks